# Is it possible to set a custom icon for a Square Connect App?

Tags: square-connect, square

I've created a Square Connect OAuth App.  When one of my customers authorizes it to a Square account they can see it listed under "My Apps".  It shows a generic icon and says "This is a custom-made application that you have authorized to access your account data using Square Connect APIs."

How can I customize that app icon?
How can I customize that description text?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the ability to customize app that is displayed in the Developer Dashboard isn't currently available.

Comment: Sorry I'm not asking about the developer dashboard, I'm asking about the customer dashboard.  I edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Currently there isn't a way to edit the app icon that is listed in the "My Apps" section of the customers Dashboard. -@RoyPaterson